# Is it possible to build an Azure pipeline from blob to on-premises SFTP relying only on AZIR?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

We have hybrid network with MS ExpressRoute connecting our on-prem environment to our Azure cloud environment.

A vendor SFTP server endpoint is available on-prem exposed via an IPsec tunnel between us and the vendor.  We NAT our private IPs to the vendor private IP exposed on the tunnel.

Is it possible to configure a data-factory pipeline that performs data-transfer between an endpoint available on-premises ( such as a SFTP server ) and Azure blob storage, where the IR process runs exclusively in the Azure compute fabric ?

So the pipeline copy-activity source & sink would both rely on linked-services that are configured with AZIR, not SHIR.

If this is possible, would it entail establishing a network route between on-premises SFTP endpoint and data-factory ?  Or between SFTP and blob storage ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and indicate whther your organisation already has a hybrid network setup, i.e. a VPN from your on prem network to the Auzre network

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes hybrid with MS ExpressRoute

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes.

There are a few options. These ones refer primarly to the SFTP side.

#### 1. Public route

Only mentioned for context. Won't (and shouldn't) be approved by security

Network team needs to open an incoming port for a range of known public internet addresses (as mentioned in the prior question) to your SFTP server. This allows your AZITR to connect.

#### 2. Managed VNET

See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint

You provision your ADF with a managed VNET. Now your AZIR has a *private* address that you can route to your SFTP server over your existing "Hybrid netowrk". This would normally by done by creating a VPN link between your on prem network (which hosts SFTP) and your Azure network hub then link the ADF endpoint to the Azure network hub.

#### 3. Pretend blob is SFTP

Instead of using SFTP as a file staging area, change your processes to drop the files directly in blob storage. You should be able to do this transparently, i.e. use your existing SFTP scripts to connect directly to blob as though it is SFTP

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support

Answer (score 0):

ADF has a list of static IPs based on the region in which it is hosted.
So you can whitelist the range of static IPs within the SFTP, post which you can access the SFTP from ADF (without the need of any SHIR)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses

Comment: Our infosec would never allow whitelist of such a wide range of public IPs.